# Why does imagemagick increase the file size of my pdf?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, image-editing, image-conversion

I have a pdf file containing a single page with scans of some documents. I want to remove obsolete parts of the page (I tried cropping and overlaying a white rectangle) and save it again. I expected the resulting file to be smaller than the original, but it's always much larger. Even when I only say `convert 1.pdf 2.pdf`, 2.pdf is six times larger than 1.pdf (1.3 vs 0.22 MB). Why is that?

I tried `display` interactively and `convert`, with similar results.
I tried `-compress` but the result is either crap or large.
Are there better alternatives to imagemagick?
Unfortunately I can't publish the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Why does imagemagick increase the file size of my pdf?**
>
> Are there better alternatives to imagemagick?

Go ahead and overlay the image part from the document as you normally would, get that saved to a PDF and then use [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com/download/) to reduce the size of the PDF document.

Once you download and install [GhostScript](http://ghostscript.com/download/) onto the machine to shrink the PDF files from, you could run the below logic to reduce the size of the PDF file from an elevated command prompt.

**Instructions**

Be sure:

1. the **GhostScript** `gswin64c.exe` file points where it's installed on your system
2. the `-sOutputFile="C:\PDFFolder\Reduced\ReducedSize.pdf"` part points to the full path folder and file location where to save the reduced size file
3. the `"C:\PDFFolder\ToReduce\Reduce.pdf"` part directly after #2 points to the full path folder and file location to shrink.

---

```
"C:\Program Files\gs\gs\bin\gswin64c.exe" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -sOutputFile="C:\PDFFolder\Reduced\ReducedSize.pdf" "C:\PDFFolder\ToReduce\Reduce.pdf"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**GhostScript Download**](http://ghostscript.com/download/)
- [**GhostScript - man page**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gs)

Comment: thanks a lot, this works nicely, now the new file is indeed smaller than the original. I just added the linux version of the command line because the windows version with absolute paths is hard to read on small screens